# TaskCanceledException causes Hangfire job to be in Processing state indefinitely

Tags: hangfire

As I understand it, Hangfire does not support async methods yet. As a workaround, I wrapped my async method calls with `AsyncContext.Run()` from [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) to make it appear to be synchronous from Hangfire point of view. Exception seems to be bubbled up correctly as expected (unwrapped from `AggregateException`).

```
    public void Task()
    {
        AsyncContext.Run(() => TaskAsync());
    }

    private async Task TaskAsync()
    {
        //...
    }
```

However, when `TaskAsync` throws `TaskCanceledException`, Hangfire does not correctly mark it as "Failed". Instead it will try to process the job again. If `TaskAsync` keeps on throwing `TaskCanceledException`, it will be stuck in that state indefinitely instead of stop retrying after 10 times as usual. 
[image]

It seems to be because Hangfire treats `OperationCanceledException` as its own control flow, instead of treating it as an exception originating from the job.  e.g. [here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/5a770aab402b820f262f0872b18c2d3304bb7128/src/Hangfire.Core/Server/Worker.cs), and [here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/5a770aab402b820f262f0872b18c2d3304bb7128/src/Hangfire.Core/Server/DefaultJobPerformanceProcess.cs).

Is there any way to get around it, other than wrapping all my Hangfire jobs with `catch TaskCanceledException` ?

Comment: I like the way how you present your question. A minor correction re: _"Hangfire does not support `async` methods yet"_: Noone ever sees the `async` keyword except you and the compiler. It is only an instruction to the compiler to perform certain code transformations, but not part of the method signature. It would perhaps be more correct to say that Hangfire does not yet support async (no code formatting!) methods, i.e. those returning a `Task` or `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who face the same problem as myself, this bug has been fixed in [Hangfire 1.4.7](http://hangfire.io/blog/2015/10/01/hangfire-1.4.7.html).

As per the changeset, Hangfire now checks that the `InnerException` is not a `TaskCanceledException`.